# Self-signed SSL certificate with only TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suite

Tags: ssl, openssl

For debug purposes I need to create a SSL certificate which will support **only** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suite . I'm not so good in this area, so what's why I nned help.

How to create "standard" certificate I'm know, but it's also allow for client use alternative cipher suites .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need create SSL certificate which will support only TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suite .

The only restrictions you can do in the certificate is if RSA or ECDSA is used for authentication because this depends on the kind of public key in the certificate. Everything else is only determined by the configuration of server and client and not by the certificate.

Comment: Thanks. This dummy question was asked because lack of knowledge in this area . after some googling this command initiate required connection configuration :

openssl s_client -cipher AES256-SHA256 -connect myhostname.local:443